# Regular Expression in python

Tags: python, regex

When the parenthesis were used in the below program output is 
`['www.google.com']`.

```
import re
teststring = "href=\"www.google.com\""
m=re.findall('href="(.*?)"',teststring)
print m;
```

If parenthesis is removed in findall function output is `['href="www.google.com"']`.

```
import re
teststring = "href=\"www.google.com\""
m=re.findall('href=".*?"',teststring)
print m;
```

Would be helpful if someone explained how it works.

Comment: Code you have provided is exactly the same. But probably you are talking about grouping in regular expressions in general.

Comment: I've fixed your example code to actually produce the output (which also were missing the quotes). I left in the redundant semicolons though; python does not need those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`re.findall()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) is quite clear on the difference:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. […] If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

So `.findall()` returns a list containing one of three types of values, depending on the number of groups in the pattern:

- 0 capturing groups in the pattern (no `(...)` parenthesis): the whole matched string (`'href="www.google.com"'` in your second example).
- 1 capturing group in the pattern: return the captured group (`'www.google.com'` in your first example).
- more than 1 capturing group in the pattern: return a tuple of all matched groups.

Use non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`) if you don't want that behaviour, or *add* groups if you want more information. For example, adding a group around the `href=` part would result in a list of tuples with two elements each:

```
>>> re.findall('(href=)"(.*?)"', teststring)
[('href=', 'www.google.com')]
```

Comment: Why should it be? It only would return a list of tuples (if that's what you meant) if there is more than 1 group.

Comment: My doubt is why href= is not included in the output even though it matches the pattern.i.e how does groups behave in this example..sorry i m new to python

Comment: @vindhya: The `href` is not grouped. Only the part matched by `(.*?)` (a capturing group) is returned. When you remove the group, the whole match is returned.